# Npm missing inside rider terminal but active in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, npm, terminal, nvm, rider

I am using `nvm` to use different versions of node currently I use either `node 18.15.0` or `node 16.17.0`. When I use my normal windows terminal (`powershell 7.3.6`) it works with no issues.

[image]

However when trying to do the same commands within Rider IDE and it's built in terminal which is also running `powershell 7.3.6` I errors

Running the same commands in the rider IDE gives me these errors.
[image]

I would expect that the results of the commands are the same independent of where I'm running powershell 7.3.6

I checked the environment variable settings for the terminal in rider and the:

- [x] `Include system environment variables:` setting is checked

Comment: Have you compared the $env:Path on both native PS and rider to see if they are the same?

Comment: Yes. Actually I just solved it myself!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it started working.

I added the system variables to riders user variables applied them, restarted rider and then removed the variables applied them and restarted rider. And now it works.